# Apache Flink: What is the difference of setParallelism() and setMaxParallelism()

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I tried to set the max parallelism for a Flink job, using the `ExecutionConfig.setMaxParallelism()` method, but it did not seem to work.

I also modified the standard WordCount example to run a few tests, and it seems the `setMaxParallelism()` method does not have any effect on either local environment or standalone cluster.

How does `setMaxParallelism()` work?

Comment: Which behavior do you expect from `setMaxParallelism()`? Are you maybe confusing it with `setParallelsim()`?

Comment: Without the setMaxParallelism line, I saw parallelism = 8 during execution, which is how the env was configured.  With the line setMaxParallelism(4), I expect to see parallelism = 4 during execution.  Is it correct?  I also tested on a local env with 16 cores, and the log file is showing 1/16 task etc. with or without the setMaxParallelism line.  I'm try to set an upper limit for max parallism for some other jobs, is this the correct understanding?  On the other hand, the setParallelsim is tested working as expected, but that's not what we are trying to do.  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Flink provides two settings:

- `setParallelism(x)` sets the parallelism of a job or operator to `x`, i.e., the number of parallel tasks for operators.
- `setMaxParallelism(y)` controls the maximum number of tasks to which keyed state can be distributed, i.e, the maximum effective parallelism of an operator. The operator can still have more tasks, but only `y` of them will have keyed state assigned and can be used for processing. The unit of distributing keyed state is called key groups.

The [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/parallel.html) explain the concepts in more detail.

Comment: Thank you Fabian for the explanation.  So under the hood, the max parallelism limits the max number of Key groups involved.  Is it because the first test I ran is not using a KeyedStream (using DataSet), setMaxParallelism therefore has no effect?

Comment: `setMaxParallelism()` does not affect the number of tasks. It is only limiting the number of key groups. Since it does not really make sense to have more tasks than key groups, Flink throws the exception that you posted in your answer.

Comment: @FabianHueske btw what's the difference between `setParallelism()` applied on `StreamExecutionEnvironment` and applied individually on `StreamOperator`s?  Let's say I've applied `env.setParallelism(10)` but used `setParallelism(1)` for sources and operators

Answer (score 0):

I ran a few more tests today, using stream instead of dataset.  This time I saw  the effect of setMaxParallelism().

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        env.getConfig().setMaxParallelism(4); // <-- effect

        DataStream<String> text = env.fromElements(WORDS);

        DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> counts = text.flatMap(new Tokenizer()).keyBy(0).sum(1);

        counts.writeAsCsv("test.dat");

        env.execute("WordCount Example");
    }
```

Interesting error the client saw,

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Vertex Flat Map's parallelism (8) is higher than the max parallelism (4). Please lower the parallelism or increase the max parallelism.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionJobVertex.<init>(ExecutionJobVertex.java:188)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph.attachJobGraph(ExecutionGraph.java:830)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraphBuilder.buildGraph(ExecutionGraphBuilder.java:232)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraphBuilder.buildGraph(ExecutionGraphBuilder.java:100)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.createExecutionGraph(JobMaster.java:1152)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.createAndRestoreExecutionGraph(JobMaster.java:1132)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.<init>(JobMaster.java:294)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobManagerRunner.<init>(JobManagerRunner.java:157)
        ... 10 more
```

Thanks